# Capture row reorder event in data table in an R Shiny WebApp

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have rendered a DataTable to UI whose rows can be reordered.
After the user has reordered the rows (by dragging), I want to read the modified dataTable or capture this event.

```
output$dtOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dtToShow <- as.data.table(lList)
    colnames(dtToShow) <- c("List")
    data.table(
        data = dtToShow), rownames = F,extensions = "RowReorder",
        server = F, escape = F, options = list(rowReorder = T,
        searching = F, ordering = F, paging = F)
})
```

Comment: You can use the [row-reorder](https://datatables.net/reference/event/row-reorder) event to capture the event. But then what do you want to do ?